# Reciept in my code keeps repeating itself and does not take into account other values [python]

Tags: python, csv

First I would like to apoligise for poor English as it is not my native tongue.

This is a program which asks a user to input a barcode , then my program finds the specified product , asks the user how many of a product they would like to purchase , if they would like to continue , calculates the total price and then is SUPPOSED to print out a reciept,howevery my problem is that the reciept repeats its values and is not rounded too two decimal places. Another major issue is that my script in the calculation only takes into account the last products , so if I ordered 2 tomatos and 2 celery sticks and asked for the price , it only calculates the 2 celery sticks

```
press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping0
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '2.80']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.20']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '1.4', '32.199999999999996']
[]
['celery', '0', '0']
```

I am pretty sure this is where the code is messing up (my reciept code)

```
def quantity():
    fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(fileOne)
    global total_price
    product_data = read_csv_file()
    matches = search_user_input(product_data)
    if matches: # Will not be True if search_user_input returned None
        print("apple")
        product, price = matches[0], matches[1]
        order = int(input("How much of {} do you want?".format(product)))
        values = [str(product), str(price), str(order*price)]
        price = str(round(price,2))
        writer.writerows((values,))
        total_price.append(order * price)
    continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
    if (continue_shopping == 0):
        fileOne.close()
        fileTwo = open("receipt.csv" , "r")
        reader = csv.reader(fileTwo)
        for row in reader:
            if row != None:
                print(row)
    elif continue_shopping==1:
        quantity()
```

And this is the whole code as a entity

```
import csv 
import locale
continue_shopping = 0
total_price = []

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
def read_csv_file():
    global total_price
    """ reads csv data and appends each row to list """
    csv_data = []
    with open("task2.csv") as csvfile:
         spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
         for row in spamreader:
             csv_data.append(row)
    return csv_data


def get_user_input():
    global total_price
    """ get input from user """
    while True:
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number: "))
            return GTIN # Breaks the loop and returns the value
        except:
            print ("Oops! That was not a valid number.  Try again")


def search_user_input(product_data):
    global total_price
    repeat=""
    # Pass the csv data as an argument
    """ search csv data for string """
    keep_searching = True

    while keep_searching:
        gtin = get_user_input()
        for row in product_data:
            if row[0] == str(gtin):
                product = row[1]
                price = round(float(row[2]),2)
                return(product, price)
        while True:
            try:
                repeat = input("not in there? search again? If so (y), else press enter to continue")
                break
            except:
                print("please make sure you enter a valid string") 
        if repeat != 'y':
            keep_searching = False 
            return None 


def quantity():
    fileOne = open('receipt.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(fileOne)
    global total_price
    product_data = read_csv_file()
    matches = search_user_input(product_data)
    if matches: # Will not be True if search_user_input returned None
        print("apple")
        product, price = matches[0], matches[1]
        order = int(input("How much of {} do you want?".format(product)))
        values = [str(product), str(price), str(order*price)]
        writer.writerows((values,))
        total_price.append(order * price)
    continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
if continue_shopping !=0 and continue_shopping !=1:
    if (continue_shopping == 0):
        fileOne.close()
        fileTwo = open("receipt.csv" , "r")
        reader = csv.reader(fileTwo)
        for row in reader:
            if row != None:
                print(row)
    elif continue_shopping==1:
        search_user_input()
        quantity()
quantity()
```

I would appreciate any help with my program or a general pointer to the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of your question. `if continue_shopping !=0 and continue_shopping !=1:` is outside of the function and, clearly, if that previous statement isn't `True` then `if (continue_shopping == 0):` immediately following it can _never_ be `True` either.

Comment: The way to get an answer to your question is to improve it (with a [mcve], asking a single clear question, etc.), not to repost it the next day.

Comment: Ok , will do , I will look at the link